# Complexidade de algorítimo simples

Tags: algoritmo, matemática, complexidade-de-algoritmo

estou tendo dificuldade nesse exercício de complexidade de algorítimos, alguém pode dar uma luz?

Provar que, se f(n) = -n então f(n) é O(1).

Uma ideia que tive foi que para qualquer n positivo, f(n) será menor que n. Não sei se está correto

Comment: "*para qualquer n positivo, f(n) será menor que n*", não vejo como isso possa afetar a complexidade do algoritmo. No caso, acho que bastaria comentar que o número de operações executadas para calcular a saída é constante, portanto é O(1).

Comment: Acho que  entendi seu ponto, mas e para "provar" isso? não teria que ter alguma linguagem matemática?

Comment: @Bakun, basta mostrar que a quantidade de operações executadas não é afetada pelo tamanho do entrada. Isso é, por sinal, a definição de `O(1)`

Answer (score 1):

Tudo que f(n) faz é retornar -n. Calcular o negativo de um número é uma operação de complexidade constante, é igual para todos os números. E um algoritmo de complexidade constante (seja grande ou pequena) é O(1).